# Resolve observable in Angular 5 with no results

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-observables

I'm getting images using the Box API via a service that returns an Observable. When no images are found, the Observable never resolves. While the API is being called I'm showing a loading spinner. I want the Observable to resolve even when there are no results so I that can dismiss the loading spinner.

I'd prefer to not set a timeout.

BoxService:

```
getProjectImages(projectId: string, featured?: boolean, thumbnail?: boolean) {
    const featuredFlag = (featured !== undefined ? (featured ? flag.YES : flag.NO) : undefined);
    const thumbnailFlag = (thumbnail !== undefined ? (thumbnail ? flag.YES : flag.NO) : undefined);
    return this.search(projectId, featuredFlag, thumbnailFlag)
            .map(files => Observable.of<FileInfo>(...files)) // for each box file create an observable
            .concatAll() // flatten Observable<Observable<FileInfo>> to Observable<FileInfo>
            .map(f => this.getRepresentations(f.id)) // For each FileInfo get it's Representation
            .concatAll(); // flatten Observable<Observable<FileRepresentation>>
}
```

Component:

```
this.boxService.getProjectImages(String(project.projectId), true, false)
    .catch(err => observer.error(err))
    .subscribe((image: FileRepresentation) => {

        // hide loading spinner
        // If images are found, display images.
        // Currently, this is only reached if images are found.

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

subscription are asynch so they will reached only if data is found/no error;

If you are calling an api/service to get Images, the http response will arrive shortly with either error,empty data or the actual images.In case of empty data or images, your text below subscription will definitely be called.If that is not the case for empty images then its because the http response is returning error that you are not catching or your manipulation of the returning data is incorrect.

example:

```
getImages():Observable<Images[]>{
     return this._http.get(this.getImagesURL)
     .catch( this.handleError );
 }

private handleError( error: any ) {
    if ( error instanceof Response ) {//Backend Error
        //.json() parsing failed from server
        console.log( "Error:"+error.text() );
        return Observable.throw( error.text() );
    }
    //otherwise the server returned error code status
    return Observable.throw( error );
}

  this.dataService.getImages().subscribe(data=>{
      console.log("Response has arrived it may be empty");
  }),
  error=>{
      console.log( "ERROR:" + error );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your observable *completes* so that the `finally` operator is called. You use the `finally` operator to execute a callback after the stream is done.

```
this.boxService.getProjectImages(String(project.projectId), true, false)
.catch(err => observer.error(err))
.finally(()=> { /** turn off loading indicator **/ })
.subscribe((image: FileRepresentation) => {
});
```

It's not clear to me how you've created the observable. You call the `this.search()` method which returns an observable, but is this an infinite observer?

If the `complete()` method is never called or you don't have an operator in place that completes the stream. It will remain open indefinitely as long as there are subscribers.

You can use operators like `take(#)` or `first()` to auto-complete an observable after some items have been emitted.

I would need to see how `this.search()` works to provide a better answer, but first try using `finally()` and see if that does the trick. Maybe the observable is being properly completed.